# Order of Operations, BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

When using BigDecimal I am getting the wrong expected value. I know it is to do with the order of operations and the way java is reading it, but I'm not sure how to rectify it.
Expected output = 5.1

```
length = 2.4
width = 1
effectivedepth = 1.5

Using brackets 
// (length * effectivedepth) + (width * effectivedepth) = Surfacearea50perDepth
 //(2.4 * 1.5) + (1 * 1.5) = 5.1
  surfacearea50perDepth = length.multiply(effectivedepth.add(width.multiply(effectivedepth)));

Output = 7.2


thanks in advance
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Can you share **working** code such that others could reproduce your situation?

Comment: Hi Nico, I got round the problem by taking out the common factor (effective depth) and placing on the outside of the brackets

Answer (score 0):

Solved, placed the effective depth outside the bracket..
effective depth(width+length)=SA

```
    surfacearea50perDepth = effectivedepth.multiply(width.add(length));
```